# DrawIconEx and DrawIcon only draw a non animated Loading icon

Tags: c++, winapi, cursor

I'm currently working on camstudio_cl [(here if interested)](http://camstudio.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/camstudio/trunk/CamStudioCommandline/).
The problem now is that I have to draw the cursor into a HDC.

This is how it is currently done (shorten):

```
HCURSOR hcur = GetCursor();
::DrawIconEx( hMemDC, xPoint.x, xPoint.y, hcur, 0, 0, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);
```

The problem is, this only draws a non animated Loading cursor, no matter which cursor is shown on screen.
But if you replace the HCURSOR with an defined HICON, in this case a hand, it works:

```
::DrawIconEx( hMemDC, xPoint.x, xPoint.y, LoadCursor(IDC_HAND), 0, 0, 0, NULL, DI_NORMAL);
```

So the problem seems to be the GetCursor() function, but it's not null and I retrieve a handle.
I also tried to create my own cursor with GetIconInfo and the help of this [thread](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=363170), but I failed. It's only a black square with some white dots in it.

I hope someone can help me with this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "it works" since the hand icon doesn't animate. If you want animation, you need to pass a frame number as the `istepIfAniCur` parameter.

Comment: With "it works" I mean it draws the hand instead of the loading icon.

Comment: Then I don't understand what "doesn't work" in the first case. It draws a non-animating Loading cursor, and the second case which "works" draws a non-animating Hand cursor. Or is the problem that you think it should be showing some other cursor instead of Loading? Remember, GetCursor returns your local cursor, not the global cursor.

Comment: ohhh! right! forgot that! Thanks, cant give a comment a "question answered" but it has..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Raymond Chen I got it... just want to have this question answered as marked.

I had to get the global instead of the local cursor handle.

```
  CURSORINFO pci;
  pci.cbSize = sizeof(CURSORINFO);
  GetCursorInfo(&pci);
  return pci.hCursor;
```